# Synonym for "slice and dice"

Tags: phrases

Can anyone provide me with a more professional way of saying "slice and dice"?  For example, "This new interactive report allows you to slice and dice information regarding your clients"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never before seen slice and dice used figuratively like that to be honest. Generally, I would recommend more literal options, but if you want to use a figure of speech that preserve the cutting metaphor slice 'n dice communicates, then I would suggest using the word [Dissect](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/dissect). Literally meaning "to cut into pieces" the American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster also defines it as meaning:

> 3. To divide into its constituent parts, for the purpose of examination; as, dissect your mind; dissect a paragraph.

Dissect information is sometimes used in professional contexts such as this excerpt from *[Big Data Analytics and Technology for Effective Planning](https://books.google.com/books?id=wDz_taCo5dYC&pg=PA14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIup_VzbjgAhVIIDQIHTn_AGMQ6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, edited by Arun K. Somani and Ganesh Chandra Deka:

> Even in the event that you can discover and dissect information rapidly and place it in the best possible connection for the group of onlookers that will expand the data, the estimation of information for basic leadership purposes will be imperiled if the information is not exact or opportune.

[The ngrams library](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=examine+information%2Cdissect+information%2Canalyze+information&year_start=1902&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexamine%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdissect%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canalyze%20information%3B%2Cc0) doesn't really have dissect collocated with information before 1964, and it is a rare collocation at that, but information does not seem like a categorically different word from the other examples to me, and unlike slice 'n dice, it is has enough precedent to past the minimal threshold to be displayed on the graph. That is not to say that *slice 'n dice information* is unprecedented in Google Books, but [it is so negligibly rare that ngrams does not even chart it as of yet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slice+%27n+dice+information&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), which makes *dissect information* more popular than *slice 'n dice information* if not only by default.

Still, it is rare, and out of the options that do chart it seems to be the rarest:

[image: This is an ngram that has graph smoothing turned off and ranges from 1902 to 2008, showing that analyze is by far the most popular option, followed distantly by examine and with dissect barely passing the noise threshold.]

It is probably worth noting that the rarity is in part due to a somewhat more specific meaning though.

Answer (score 1):

> This new interactive report allows you to rearrange and analyze information regarding your clients in a number of different ways

[Not quite literally:] https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slice_and_dice

Answer (score 0):

As in"

> "This new interactive report allows you to **data mine** information
>   regarding your clients"

**data mining**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/data+mining)

> n. The extraction of useful, often previously unknown information from
>   large databases or data sets.